# Javascript - how to retrieve html tag's value from a response

Tags: javascript, html

Sending HTTP GET to a server. Having the payload response returned from the server, i need to extract the value of a html tag. I don't know the code to do this

This is the code to send HTTP GET to the server:

```
<html>
 <script>
  function TEST()
  {
   var data = null;
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.withCredentials = true;
   xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
   if (this.readyState === 4) 
   { console.log(this.responseText);}
       });
   xhr.open("GET", "https://webadmin.domain.local/authenticate.html");
   xhr.send(data);
  }
 </script>
 <b onmouseover = "TEST()">pass mouse here</b>
</html>
```

The server returned response, and i need to extract Session-Key's value:

```
<input type="hidden" name ="Session-Key" value ="05aa6221dc982adb"/>
```

I need to extract Session-Key's value so i can use it for the next request to the server. What's the code to do this in my script?

Comment: Well, have you tied: `document.getElementsByName('Session-Key')[0].getAttribute('value')`?

Answer (score 0):

str is the  response as an html string received from api

```js
  let str = '<input type="hidden" name ="Session-Key" value ="05aa6221dc982adb"/>'
     let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
         let val = doc.firstElementChild.getAttribute('value');
         console.log(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set

```
xhr.responseType = "document"
```

and then get **xhr.responseXML** instead of **xhr.responseText**.

**xhr.responseXML** will be the instance of **HTMLDocument**, so you will be able to use **querySelector** method to get the data you need.

```
// ...
if (xhr.responseXML) {
    const sessionKeyNode = xhr.responseXML.querySelector('[name="Session-Key"]');

    if (sessionKeyNode) {
        console.log(sessionKeyNode.value);
    }
}
// ...
```